# Curved edges with GraphElementData no longer working in Mathematica 13.1

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I just noticed that it seems no longer possible to get curved edges on graphs in Mathematica 13.1 using GraphElementData. For example, the following code works on versions 12.x:

```
Graph[{1, 2}, {1 -> 2},
EdgeShapeFunction -> ({GraphElementData[{"CurvedEdge", "Curvature" -> -1}][##]} &)]
```

But in Mma 13.1 this now produces error and no graph. Could anyone confirm this?

Comment: It seems it has been moved to the `GraphComputation` context in version 13.1, your code also works on 13.0.1. In 13.1 you can remove `GraphElementData` like: `EdgeShapeFunction -> {{"CurvedEdge", "Curvature" -> -1}}` but if you want the old syntax use ```EdgeShapeFunction -> ({GraphComputation`GraphElementData[{"CurvedEdge", "Curvature" -> -1}][##]} &)```

Comment: or you could do Graph[{1, 2}, {1 -> 2}, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> {{"CurvedEdge", "Curvature" -> -1}}]

Comment: @Ben Izd, thanks a lot for the help! I'm noticing that in certain situations in 13.1, GraphElementData still works fine in the System` context. However, the simpler syntax is clearly preferable.

Comment: @BenIzd Please convert your comment to an answer!

Answer (score 6):

It seems it has been moved to the `` GraphComputation`‌ `` context in version 13.1 (your code works fine on 13.0.1).

In 13.1 you can remove `GraphElementData` like:

```
Graph[ ... , EdgeShapeFunction -> {{"CurvedEdge", "Curvature" -> -1}} ]
```

but if you want the old syntax use:

```
Graph[ ... , EdgeShapeFunction -> ({GraphComputation`GraphElementData[{"CurvedEdge", "Curvature" -> -1}][##]} &) ]
```

Both give the same output in 13.1:

[image]

Comment: But not in v13.3, where your second example returns with error, no matter whether `GraphComputation` is included before `GraphElementData` or not.